# Cannot get XML from webpage to String in Java

Tags: java, xml, http

I have a problem with getting XML from this [webpage](https://www.strava.cz/foxisapi/foxisapi.dll/istravne.istravne.process?xmljidelnickyA&zarizeni=3148). In the browser it shows correctly and there is no issue, but when it comes to Java, it is different.

I've tried two methods which both of them resulted in exception.

```java
// Method 1 - Using Java's URL
URL url = new URL(/* mentioned link */);
String rawXML = new String(url.openStream().readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response
```

```java
// Method 2 - Using Apache's HTTP client
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(/* mentioned link */);
String rawXML = EntityUtils.toString(HttpClients.createDefault().execute(httpGet).getEntity()); // org.apache.http.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response
```

Downloading this webpage with `wget` and using argument `--content-on-error` works but it is unreliable since wget is not always available on all systems like Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response does not contains headers so java rejects it

```
wget "https://www.strava.cz/foxisapi/foxisapi.dll/istravne.istravne.process?xmljidelnickyA&zarizeni=3148" -O so-69226464.html
--2021-09-17 13:44:29--  https://www.strava.cz/foxisapi/foxisapi.dll/istravne.istravne.process?xmljidelnickyA&zarizeni=3148
Resolving www.strava.cz (www.strava.cz)... 82.99.180.77
Connecting to www.strava.cz (www.strava.cz)|82.99.180.77|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 No headers, assuming HTTP/0.9
Length: unspecified
```

This java class making a raw HTTP GET request is able to get the contents. Based on [this](https://code.joejag.com/2012/how-to-send-a-raw-http-request-via-java.html) page.
The request sent is

```
GET /foxisapi/foxisapi.dll/istravne.istravne.process?xmljidelnickyA&zarizeni=3148 HTTP/1.1\r\n
User-Agent: RawHttpGet\r\n
Host: www.strava.cz\r\n
Accept: */*\r\n
```

Java code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class RawHttpGet {
    private static String hostname = "www.strava.cz";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Socket socket = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(hostname, 443);

        // UTF-8 encdoding
        //BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        // Encoding for this request
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "Cp1250"));
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer("GET /foxisapi/foxisapi.dll/istravne.istravne.process?xmljidelnickyA&zarizeni=3148 HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        buff.append("User-Agent: RawHttpGet\r\n");
        buff.append("Accept: */*\r\n");
        buff.append("Host: " + hostname + "\r\n");
        buff.append("\r\n");
        System.out.println(" * Request");
        System.out.println(buff.toString());
        // send message
        out.write(buff.toString());
        out.flush();

        // read response
        System.out.println(" * Response");
        // Default system encoding
        //System.out.println(new String(socket.getInputStream().readAllBytes()));
        // Encoding for this request
        System.out.println(new String(socket.getInputStream().readAllBytes(), "Cp1250"));

        out.close();
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works exactly how I expected it to. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Mayuna fixed code to use SSL port 443. You can still use port 80 by commenting/uncommenting appropriately.

Comment: don't convert xml to characters/Strings/Readers.  that is a great way to destroy.  keep it as bytes and Input/OutputStreams

Comment: @jtahlborn thx for the suggestion, searched for a way to change but didn't found one quickly so some refactoring is needed I guess.

Comment: use InputStream and OutputStream and byte[] to copy bytes between.

Comment: @jtahlborn something as `System.out.println(new String(socket.getInputStream().readAllBytes()));` should work it seems.

Comment: Thanks, I'll update my code.